# How can I enable scrollbars on the WPF Grid?

Tags: .net, wpf, grid

How can I enable scrollbars on WPF Grid? The grid is inside a stack panel.

Comment: @McGarnagle I meant Grid and not Data Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong but I don't think Grid has a scroll viwer built in. You could do something like:

```
 <ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
      <Grid />
    </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Note: Be aware that Stackpanels content generally will not vertically stretch the way you would expect

Comment: You could also just wrap the grid (without wrapping the stack panel) if you want just that portion of the window to scroll.

Comment: The scroll viewer should have fixed height (especially in the case where you want just the grid to scroll).

In the case of the whole window scrolling, fixed height shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @LordTakkera Correct again.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** I assumed that the OP meant `DataGrid` ... if `Grid` was intended, then I will defer to @TMan's answer ...

---

The characteristic of a StackPanel is that it presents an infinite (vertical or horizontal) dimension.  So if the DataGrid is its child, then it will see it has infinite space, and use up the full amount it needs (hence no scroll).

To enable scrolling, you will need to limit the DataGrid's height somehow.  For example set a `Height` or `MaxHeight` on the grid.  Or use another panel like `Grid` that doesn't present infinite space.

You could also consider wrapping the StackPanel itself in a `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: I don't think limiting the Grid's height would force scroll bars, the ScrollViewer is the correct approach

Comment: @LordTakkera Right ... I assumed "WPF Grid" meant "DataGrid", but I suppose I didn't have much basis for that assumption.

Comment: @McGarnagle I meant wpf grid and not datagrid. Thanks for your answer. I liked your explanation, your answer was usefull and hence upvoted it.